My consent to the data-dump is not stored server side
When you ask me to consent to certain conditions like

I understand that this file is being provided to me for my own use and for projects that do not include training a large language model (LLM), and that should I distribute this file for the purpose of LLM training, Stack Overflow reserves the right to decline to allow me access to future downloads of this data dump.

shouldn't you at least send that consent to your servers as well? Your legal team might find that convenient in the case where they sue me and need data-records to support their claim.

Because now I have obtained a data-dump where I didn't consent to your legalese and I might or might not feel restricted by your additional terms.
I know this is all for nothing but shouldn't you take this a bit more serious? I want the whole feature gone. But if the feature stays it needs to be on par. At least in compliance with all 'legal threats' you've extensively communicated about because it mattered so much. Storing my consent matters. Where it matters if that prevents me from getting the data dump is up to you.
Maybe a quick fix is rolling back the change and reinstate the upload to the Web Archive.

Don’t interrupt your opponent when they’re making a mistake?

Is the checkbox even necessary for anything? Even when dealing with privacy, double consent is often used but isn't strictly necessary. The fact that you need to view the page, the full policy/terms is available, and you need to click a button should be sufficient to give consent as it's a "clear affirmative action". The fact that the button is disabled until a button is clicked seems to be extra. My understanding is that clicking the enabled button is logged/recorded. Do you really need more?

Especially since its not clear that the statement has any legal meaning, just advertising something they had a legal right to do anyway. So why would it have any relevance regarding your claim about suing?

Thankfully the data contained in the dump is under a license which forbids adding additional downstream restrictions, so whether or not you click the checkbox, the text surrounding it is meaningless.

As I said on the Tavern chatroom, I am pretty sure that right now you could even just use the developer tool to enable the button without clicking the checkbox and it would still work... This looks like the work of a team that did have to do something but didn't want to do something. I wonder what the employees general sentiment for these choices is.

I would also add that I still don't see HOW they can hope to prove that whoever downloaded a dump (the only person that signed the agreement) was the user who trained a specific LLM.

If the client doesn’t let you download it without consent, and you have downloaded it, the record of your download is the record of consent, n’est pas?

@Jeremy I'm not sure. In all systems I've build that involved user consent I'm required to store their consent explicitly as demanded by the legal staff that scrutinized my implementation. I assume they wouldn't be so picky if circumstantial evidence would count as well. Maybe this case is special, I doubt it.

The terms of service contain the usual wording allowing SE to ban you at any time for any reason or no reason whatsoever, so they don't actually need your consent on the data dump for anything. The only reason that text is there is to threaten you to not use it for LLM development, it has no legal signficance.

@Robotnik they cannot add restrictions on how to use the data but they can ban you from the site and downloading said data in the future. CC-BY-SA has no provision forcing them to distribute the content to everyone wanting it. Obviously you can get someone else to download and share it with you if/when you get banned, but SE can be as difficult as they want about sharing the dumps.

@Kryomaani - If they wanted to stop the dump entirely, they can. But they can't provide the dump to SOME individual users but not others, that is an "additional restriction" which is against the terms of the license: "No additional restrictions — You may not apply legal terms or technological measures that legally restrict others from doing anything the license permits.". If they continue to provide the dump, and continue to provide it under CC-BY-SA (they have to, due to the content it contains), then they can't individually lock out users. Hence why the checkbox is meaningless.

@SPArcheon "don't attribute malice in place of..." well, not stupidity, but definitely rushing. This whole thing feels like it was rushed out last minute.

@Robotnik CC-BY-SA does not require them to share the dump with anyone. It only means that anyone who has the dump may share it with anyone. As ineffectual as limited initial sharing may be, it does not  add a restriction to the license.

@MisterMiyagi Which is why I said if they wanted to, they could stop the dump entirely (they actually tried that, btw, but got massive backlash from it). My point is: if the dump is available for some people then it is still licensed under CC-BY-SA, and if they in any way restrict or prevent people from downloading it (based on arbitrary Terms of Use breach or other technological measure), then they are in breach of the CC-BY-SA terms.

To be clear: I am (personally) in support of some sort of restriction on the use of SO/SE data for AI purposes. But as written, the CC-BY licenses are pretty clear, imo. I also think measures like the checkbox are too little, too late. Ultimately - short of a CC-BY-SA 5.0 that explicitly protects against AI remix/transformation purposes (unlikely to happen), I don't think there's anything that SO can really do. I don't envy their position: trying to protect their service, balance the needs (and rights!) of the community, and also make a buck off the AI companies harvesting their data.

@Robotnik that is not a correct interpretation of CC-BY-SA, I'm afraid. They cannot prevent anyone else from sharing dumps they have already obtained, but they absolutely can pick and choose who they themselves share them to. If you believe CC-BY-SA has language that forces them to provide data to everyone equally, please point out where. I'm fairly sure it does not.

We’ve considered how the user response is being recorded and have decided to keep the feature as is. We’ll update this post if we decide to make changes in the future.
